# Simple D3 demo not working with altered structure

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was following the [official](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7322386) tutorial. Since the structure was pretty rudimentary I decided to do a cleaner one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<title>D3</title>
<style>
    .chart div {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        background-color: steelblue;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 1px;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
        .range([0, 420]);

    d3.select(".chart")
        .selectAll("div")
        .data(data)
    .enter().append("div")
        .style("width", function(d) { return d * 10 + "px"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d; });

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="chart"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

But that is not working. This is the error I'm getting:

```
d3.html:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined
```

I've found in [D3 api](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#scales-d3-scale) that the method scale.linear is now called using scaleLinear.

The output error disappeared but I still can't see anything, while copypasting the example with scale.linear old method works.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's `d3.scaleLinear()`, not `d3.scale.linear()`. But I'm curious: what changes did you make?

Comment: Just read my question, I already stated that O changed the scale.linear method and still not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is on the `head`, and it's being parsed before the div with a class "chart" being generated .

Just move all your script to the end of the `body`, *after* the div you are selecting:

```css
.chart div {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        background-color: steelblue;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 1px;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart"></div>
<script>
  var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
        .range([0, 420]);

    d3.select(".chart")
        .selectAll("div")
        .data(data)
    .enter().append("div")
        .style("width", function(d) { return d * 10 + "px"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
  </script>
</body>
```

If you want to keep the script in the `head`, for whatever reason, just change `d3.select(".chart")` for `d3.select("body")`:

```css
div {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        background-color: steelblue;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 1px;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<head>
<title>D3</title>
<style>
    .chart div {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        background-color: steelblue;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 1px;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
        .range([0, 420]);

    d3.select("body")
        .selectAll("div")
        .data(data)
    .enter().append("div")
        .style("width", function(d) { return d * 10 + "px"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d; });

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: Actually, there is not even a `<head>` in OP's code, just a closing `</head>`!

Comment: I moved the D3 script into the head tag and moved the JavaScript out of the HTML and it worked https://jsbin.com/devedorawo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @JNewton That's probably because of the way JSBin deals with JavaScript code. Look at your HTML: if that was a real web page, were is the script? Or the `src` for the script?

Comment: "That's probably because of the way JSBin deals with JavaScript code" What do you mean? I doesn't really matter common practice is at the bottom or as low down the HTML as possible, but embedded JavaScript in the HTML is bad practice (not invalided) and makes it un-testable.

Comment: Look at your HTML: where is the code? You said: "I moved the JavaScript out of the HTML and it worked". Where is the code being called? Where is the src?

Comment: Working with embedded JavaScript in the body is just what I was trying to avoid (as shows the official tutorial).

Comment: `<script src="https://static.jsbin.com/js/render/edit.js?3.39.12"></script>` the reference is in the HTML?

Comment: @Pablo, you can put the script in an external file and call it, but the principle is the same: the reference has to come *after* the div with that given class being created.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado The second one feels like a bit of a hack begging the question. I'd rather see the code wrapped in a `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { });` to not run before the DOM is ready. I am surprised no one has brought up jQuery yet ;-)